# OpenGL ES 2.0 - rotate point around pivot point 2D (vertex shader)

Tags: matrix, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I'm trying to rotate vertices around some point in 2D. 
I found @Rabbid76 solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156351/776388 but I need to rotate around z-vector.

Comment: Read about [How to use Pivot Point in Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804658/how-to-use-pivot-point-in-transformations/56806370#56806370)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution

```
vec2 rotate(vec2 point, float degree, vec2 pivot)
{
    float radAngle = -radians(degree);// "-" - clockwise
    float x = point.x;
    float y = point.y;

    float rX = pivot.x + (x - pivot.x) * cos(radAngle) - (y - pivot.y) * sin(radAngle);
    float rY = pivot.y + (x - pivot.x) * sin(radAngle) + (y - pivot.y) * cos(radAngle);

    return vec2(rX, rY);
}
```